# Keycloak client deployment best practice

Tags: keycloak

So I want to deploy a client-app (java, with spring security, if that matters) to different companies. The keycloak will obviously run on servers of my organization but the client-app as to run on the servers of the client-companies.

1. Should the keycloak-client's access type be public or confidential?
2. i.e. what is the client-secret used for? (Encryption)?
3. Is it therefore a problem if the companies admins can theoretically read the secret by decompiling the jar of the client-app I give them?

Concerning the valid redirect URIs: Idealy I would like to use grant-type: password, so the user of the company enters his credentials into the frontend of the company deployed client-app and it logs into keycloak. Potentially the client-app deployed in the company is only reacable from the company intranet.

4. What can the redirect URI be for this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Should the keycloak-client's access type be public or confidential?

From the [RFC 6749 OAuth 2.0 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.1) one can read:

> confidential
>
> ```
>   Clients capable of maintaining the confidentiality of their
>   credentials (e.g., client implemented on a secure server with
>   restricted access to the client credentials), or capable of secure
>   client authentication using other means.
> ```
>
> public
>
> ```
>   Clients incapable of maintaining the confidentiality of their
>   credentials (e.g., clients executing on the device used by the
>   resource owner, such as an installed native application or a web
>   browser-based application), and incapable of secure client
> ```

Since you are not using a *pure* web-browser application, or a mobile phone, but rather a web application with a **secure backend**, you should use a `confidential client`.

> i.e. what is the client-secret used for? (Encryption)?

From the Keycloak documentation:

> Confidential clients are required to provide a client secret when they
> exchange the temporary codes for tokens. Public clients are not
> required to provide this client secret.

Therefore, you need the `client-secret` because you have chosen a `confidential client`. The `client-secret` is used so that the application requesting the access token from Keycloak can be properly authenticated. In your case, the servers from the companies (using your app) requesting an access token from Keycloak. Consequently, Keycloak has to ensure that the server making the request is *legit*.

That is the purpose of the `client-secret`. It is similar to when you go to the ATM and request money, the bank *knows* that you are the owner of that resource (*i.e,* the bank account) if you have inserted the correct code (i.e., analogous to a client-secret).

> Is it therefore a problem if the companies admins can theoretically
> read the secret by decompiling the jar of the client-app I give them?

The `client_secret` has to be known by the application requesting the token (*i.e.,* the company) and the authorization server (*i.e.,* Keycloak). So in theory, if the companies do not *mind* their admins having access to such information, it should be fine for you. At the end of the day, the `client-secret` has to be known by both parties anyway. A way of mitigating potential problems with the leaking of client secrets is to change client-secrets once in a while, and communicate that change to interested parties.

As long as one company cannot reverse engineer the client secret of the other company you should be fine.

> What can the redirect URI be for this case?

It should be the URL of the frontend leading page of the company deploying the client-app, after the user has been successfully authenticated.

Bear in mind, however:

> You should take extra precautions when registering valid redirect URI
> patterns. If you make them too general you are vulnerable to attacks.
> See Threat Model Mitigation chapter for more information.

([source](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_unspecific-redirect-uris))